# Install applications in Ubuntu core

Tags: apt, firefox, snap, ubuntu-core

I installed Ubuntu Core and found that it used Snap for application installation. I want to install many applications on this system such as firefox, chrome, and many more. How can I do it? And is it possible to install apt-get or yum any how?

Comment: You can search for apps using `snappy search firefox` for example.  Once you find the app, you can run `sudo snappy install appname` to install it.  Core is not meant to work with `apt-get`, although I did hear a case of someone using it before.

Comment: @Dorian it returns: The search "firefox" returned 0 snaps

Answer (score 20):

To get some apps not snapped yet on my Ubuntu Core arm i used the classic snap:

> sudo snap install classic --devmode --edge

then

> sudo classic

then apt-get is available

Comment: Here is the link reference https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/developer-setup

Answer (score 2):

No, Ubuntu Core is completely snap-based: apt is not available. Ubuntu Core mostly targets headless or kiosk-type devices, and as such doesn't ship with a window manager etc. Kiosk software typically uses Mir. You probably don't want it for a normal desktop environment; you can install snaps on the classic desktop release.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I wan to use U-Core for Digital Signage solution, and data I want to show on Firefox or Chrome. Also I have one daemon which requires packages like, npm, nodejs etc.

Comment: Ah, that's totally doable. I'm not sure that Firefox or Chrome will work with Mir, though-- you may need to use more of an embedded browser, I'm not sure. [This walkthrough](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/mir-snaps/) might include more information. Regarding your daemon, you simply need to package it as a snap. `npm` and `nodejs` are supported within Snapcraft, so just [read up on how to create snaps](https://snapcraft.io/https://snapcraft.io/) and you should be good to go.